# Oracle SQL Developer ANY() Function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, any

I wrote the query (oracle sql) as below and I saw red highlight on any() function ([any() function problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXKm2.jpg)). Is it the Oracle Developer error or my mistake? if it is my mistake, how can I change it?

```
SELECT * 
FROM EMP
WHERE (DEPTNO, SAL) = ANY(SELECT DEPTNO, MAX(SAL) FROM EMP GROUP BY DEPTNO);
```

oracle developer version: 21.4.1.
error message in detail:

> syntax error (scalar_subquery_expression := ( ...

Comment: What message appears if you hover over the `ANY` keyword? What version of SQL Developer are you using? Does the query error when you try to execute it?

Comment: Ignore it. SQL Developer wrongly recognized it as a syntax error, but successfully executes the statement anyway.

Comment: @EJEgyed oops, I added the oracle developer version and error message

Comment: @Littlefoot Yes It was successfully executed, but the oracle developer any(two columns) reports the error regardless of any() function returns one row ..., however any(single column) does not report the error.

Comment: Version 20.4.1.407 works fine...

Comment: By the way, `any` is an operator (like `=`), not a function. A function returns a value.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know much about the internal workings of SQL Developer. End of disclaimer. The question is, since the query runs without error on the database server, why does SQL Developer say there's an error? How is that possible? ANSWER: SQL Developer interjects itself between your query (simply a string) and the Oracle parser (running on the server) which is supposed to check syntax, among other things. SQL Developer takes it upon itself to check your syntax BEFORE sending it to the server - and its checker has a bug.

Comment: Perhaps at least in part in anticipation of the possibility of such bugs, the developers of SQL Developer allow you to submit your query to the database server even if it (SQL Developer) thinks you have syntax errors. It allows the database parser to check your query and either confirm SQL Developer's opinion or disagree with it and run your query anyway.

Answer (score 4):

That's the SQL Developer client side parser saying it doesn't recognize that pattern/keyword.

If you put your mouse over that, you'll see why it thinks what it thinks.

[image: If it's valid SQL, then this would be a bug.]

I can run this, it's valid SQL, it's a bug. I'll log this for you. Thanks for the report/test case!

*Disclaimer: I'm the product manager for SQL Developer.*